# iOS key strokes without displaying keyboard

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, keystroke, external-accessory, uikeyinput

I have an external scanner which basically emulates key strokes if the keyboard is active. I tested and whenever the textfield focus is on, it emulates the key strokes. But i don't want to show the keyboard to user.

Can i get the key strokes without showing the keyboard to user? or is it possible to have an off screen keyboard active all time throughout the application?

Comment: in which language  u try add language tag also

Comment: What do you mean by external scanner? How does it emulate the key strokes? Do you just mean a hardware keyboard connected via Bluetooth?

Comment: If it emulates a hardware keyboard then iOS will hide the on-screen keyboard by default

Comment: If there is no on-screen keyboard present, then its not triggering the key strokes.

Comment: Have you made a text field the first responder?  Once a text field is the responder then it will receive keystrokes. If a hardware keyboard is connected then iOS will not display a keyboard